# Automatically invoke method whenever a class method is invoked?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a base service class which, once inherited, will expose a bunch of services via methods. Before running every method should perform an access check, to see whether the running user is entitled to consume said service.
Now, I don't want to leave this to people who derive my class.

Is there any way to have each method automatically invoke some method and abort or branch according to data returned by said method?
I'd like to make this as transparent as possible to whoever implements the child classes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing that will automatically do anything for you. You have to build it yourself in your own code base. You could keep track of flags or use attributes or use some type of DI and implement an AOP functionality (aspect oriented programming / cross cutting of concerns). But the short of it is it will be code and the implementation will be dependent on other factors (such as how you expect this to behave, the calling context, etc).

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could encapsulate this.  But we'd need to have some idea of what you base class looks like. The shortest answer I can think of is to kick off all of your automatically invoked methods in the constructor of the base class.

Comment: @Casey Crookston...that's what I was thinking...in the constructor.

Comment: Just don't let the user create the derived class and you don't have to do anything special.  In other words, perform the access check in your base class constructor.

Comment: why would someone vote to close this question?  It's a really good question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a basic use case for the Template Method design pattern.

```
abstract class ServiceBase
{
    public bool ServiceMethod()
    {
        if (!CheckMethod())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return ServiceMethodImpl();
    }

    protected abstract bool ServiceMethodImpl();

    private bool CheckMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You just let the derived classes implement the core functionality, but do the needed checks in the base class.

In this way, the derived classes have no way to overcome the checks, neither they need to care about.

The derived class will just need to implement the core functionality:

```
class ServiceImpl : ServiceBase
{
    protected override bool ServiceMethodImpl()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking something involving bubbled delegates, and somehow intercepting the calls, but that's probably gonna be it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can do things like that:

```
public /* abstract */ class ServiceBase
{

  private void CheckAccess()
  {
    if ( DontHaveAccess )
      throw new NoAccessException();
  }

  public void ActionToDo()
  {
    CheckAccess();
    DoActionToDo();
  }

  protected virtual /* or abstract */ void DoActionToDo()
  {
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's probably the best way to go. Cheers!